# Crash on create AVCaptureDeviceInput FromDevice

Tags: ios, xamarin, zxing, avcapturesession

Hi I am developing a xamarin app with usage of ZXing library for barcode recognition. I use AVCaptureScannerViewController with custom overlay. Everything worked fine until I started getting these errors on `AVCaptureScannerView.StartScanning`:

```
Starting to scan...
StartScanning
critical: 
Native stacktrace:

critical:   0                                       0x00000001001569e4 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
critical:   1  libsystem_platform.dylib             0x0000000182fef348 _sigtramp + 52
critical:   2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000182f29480 <redacted> + 100
critical:   3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000182f294c8 system_set_sfi_window + 0
critical:   4   TCC                                 0x000000018616a560 <redacted> + 0
critical:   5   TCC                                 0x000000018616a45c <redacted> + 0
critical:   6   TCC                                 0x000000018616d52c <redacted> + 288
critical:   7   libxpc.dylib                        0x000000018303401c <redacted> + 80
critical:   8   libxpc.dylib                        0x0000000183033f8c <redacted> + 40
critical:   9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182de91c0 <redacted> + 16
critical:   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182df7ab4 <redacted> + 732
critical:   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182df938c <redacted> + 572
critical:   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182df90ec <redacted> + 124
critical:   13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182ff12c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
critical:   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182ff0db4 start_wqthread + 4
critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

I have found that this happens on `AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(captureDevice)`. Interesting part that I reverted every changes to previous working state, but the problem is still there.